# Creating a dateRange Scala, Joda, Java

Tags: java, scala, jodatime

I have spent hours trying to make this next piece of code work.

```scala
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Period}


def dateRange(from: DateTime, to: DateTime, step: Period): Iterator[DateTime]      =Iterator.iterate(from)(_.plus(step)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(to))

val range = {
dateRange(new DateTime(2012, 06, 30).minusYears(5), new DateTime(2000, 06, 30),new Period.months(6))
}
```

I'm trying to set up a date range array that steps through from 2000 to 2012 in 6 month increments. The problem that I am facing is the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: scala.Tuple3
at    org.joda.time.convert.ConverterManager.getInstantConverter(ConverterManager.java:165)
at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:169)
at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:241)
at tester.MomentumAlgo$class.$init$(MomentumAlgo.scala:154)
at tester.RunMomentumAlgo$$anon$1.<init>(RunMomentumAlgo.scala:86)
at tester.RunMomentumAlgo$.main(RunMomentumAlgo.scala:86)
at tester.RunMomentumAlgo.main(RunMomentumAlgo.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I seems to be something to do with the last Period.months() part, however I have no idea how to fix it. The Tuple3 error I have no idea about.

If someone can give me a different solution, that would also be great. I want a list of dates from 2000 to 2012, every 6 months.

Any questions welcome. I thought this would be a common piece of code, but there isn't much on the net about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6982. Are you entering this line by line in the REPL? I can't reproduce this with scala 2.10.0 and Joda Time 1.6 when I compile with `scalac` or when I load a file with the code in `scala`.

Comment: Hi Brian, I saw that thread before, although I'm not sure what to make of it, apart from some other people having the same issue. I am running Joda Time 1.6, but Scala 2.9.2. trying your setup on a different system now. I have tried scala 2.10.2 previously, although I dont think the problem lies there.

Comment: The problem can be reduced to this snippet `val dt = new DateTime(2013,7,16)` as noted in that thread which gives the same error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: scala.Tuple3`

Comment: I fixed the issue, I think it came down to not giving enough info to the DateTime() thing. ie it needed milliseconds, eg DateTime(2000, 06, 30,0,0,0,0). also a similar story for Period. This meant that the Compiler didn't know what to do with it. Ill put up the full code when I can.

Comment: And by the way, why are you using Joda Time 1.6 when the current version is 2.2?

Comment: 1.6 was the first one I found in my .m2 directory. :) What's your excuse @Loooit?

Comment: I was running 2.2, but changed to see if it made a difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A work around is to define the dates like this:

```
val date = new DateTime().withYear(2013).withMonthOfYear(7).withDayOfMonth(16)
```

The entire sequence in the REPL then becomes this:

```
scala> import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Period}
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Period}

scala> def dateRange(from: DateTime, to: DateTime, step: Period): Iterator[DateTime]      =Iterator.iterate(from)(_.plus(step)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(to))
dateRange: (from: org.joda.time.DateTime, to: org.joda.time.DateTime, step: org.joda.time.Period)Iterator[org.joda.time.DateTime]

scala> val from = new DateTime().withYear(2012).withMonthOfYear(6).withDayOfMonth(30).minusYears(5)
from: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2007-06-30T21:46:05.536-07:00

scala> val to = new DateTime().withYear(2000).withMonthOfYear(6).withDayOfMonth(30)
to: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2000-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00

scala> val range = dateRange(from, to, new Period().withMonths(6))
range: Iterator[org.joda.time.DateTime] = non-empty iterator

scala> range.toList
res4: List[org.joda.time.DateTime] = List(
2000-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00,
2000-12-30T21:46:26.186-08:00,
2001-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00,
2001-12-30T21:46:26.186-08:00,
2002-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00,
2002-12-30T21:46:26.186-08:00,
2003-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00,
2003-12-30T21:46:26.186-08:00,
2004-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00,
2004-12-30T21:46:26.186-08:00,
2005-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00,
2005-12-30T21:46:26.186-08:00,
2006-06-30T21:46:26.186-07:00,
2006-12-30T21:46:26.186-08:00)
```

Also, I wasn't able to reproduce this as noted in my comment. Seems the behavior is different in the REPL and the compiler.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, Here is the complete working code.

```
import org.joda.time.{Period, DateTime}

object runme {

  def main(args:Array[String]) {

  def dateRange(from: DateTime, to: DateTime, step: Period): Iterator[DateTime]
  =Iterator.iterate(from)(_.plus(step)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(to))

  val range = { dateRange(new DateTime(2000, 06, 30,0,0,0,0).minusYears(5) ,new DateTime(2013, 06, 30,0,0,0,0),new Period(0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0))}

  range.foreach(u => { 
    print(u.getYear)
    print(u.getMonthOfYear)
    println(u.getDayOfMonth)
  })

 }
}
```

I think my main problem was not having enough numbers after the `DateTime()` functions (ie the milliseconds etc.) this meant the compiler wasn't receiving all the parameters that it wanted. As mentioned by Alexey Romanov

This then prints the dates for a desired range, and can be used as an iterator.

Hope that helps others.

Thanks @Brian and others for the Help

Answer (score 6):

I was needing something similar. Here's what I came up with:

```
import org.joda.time.{Period, DateTime}

class DateRange(val start: DateTime, val end: DateTime, val step: Period, inclusive: Boolean) extends Iterable[DateTime] {
    override def iterator: Iterator[DateTime] = new DateRangeIterator

    class DateRangeIterator extends Iterator[DateTime] {
        var current = start

        override def hasNext: Boolean = current.isBefore(end) || (inclusive && current == end)

        override def next(): DateTime = {
            val returnVal = current
            current = current.withPeriodAdded(step, 1)
            returnVal
        }
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
val startOfDay: DateTime = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay()
val endOfDay: DateTime = startOfDay.plusDays(1)
val dateRange = new DateRange(startOfDay, endOfDay, Period.hours(1), false)
for (d <- dateRange) println(d)
```

Output:

```
2015-03-16T00:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T01:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T02:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T03:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T04:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T05:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T06:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T07:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T08:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T09:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T10:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T11:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T12:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T13:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T14:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T15:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T16:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T17:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T18:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T19:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T20:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T21:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T22:00:00.000-05:00
2015-03-16T23:00:00.000-05:00
```

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime` [doesn't have](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) a constructor taking three `int` arguments, so `new DateTime(2012, 06, 30)` calls `DateTime(Object)` constructor with the tuple `(2012, 06, 30)` as the argument. The documentation says:

> Constructs an instance from an `Object` that represents a datetime.
>
> If the object implies a chronology (such as `GregorianCalendar` does), then that chronology will be used. Otherwise, ISO default is used. Thus if a `GregorianCalendar` is passed in, the chronology used will be GJ, but if a Date is passed in the chronology will be ISO.
>
> The recognised object types are defined in `ConverterManager` and include `ReadableInstant`, `String`, `Calendar` and `Date`. The `String` formats are described by `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`.

Unsurprisingly, `ConverterManager` doesn't know what to do with a Scala tuple, which results in the exception.

> If someone can give me a different solution, that would also be great. I want a list of dates from 2000 to 2012, every 6 months.

If you actually want dates, the better type to use is [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (which does have the constructor you want, by the way). If you want `DateTime` at the start of these dates, then you need to think about what time zone to use.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this simple solution:

```scala
def generateDateRange(from: LocalDate, to: LocalDate): List[Date] = {
    if(from.compareTo(to) > 0) Nil
    from :: generateDateRange(from.plusDays(1), to)
}
```

We recursively build a list of dates by prepending the start of the range to the new range which starts a day later.

Answer (score 1):

I had some small changes to the code of hucko

```
private def generateDateRange(from: LocalDate, to: LocalDate): List[LocalDate] = {
    if (from.compareTo(to) > 0) Nil
    else from :: generateDateRange(from.plusDays(1), to)
}
```