# List of dates from a date to current date

Tags: java, scala, date, jodatime

I am trying to get a list of dates in `scala`

```
val savePoint:java.util.Date=                               //olderDate
var days = List[String]()
for (date<-savePoint to java.util.Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd") by date.plusDays(1)){
    days::=date
}
```

but getting error

```
 value to is not a member of java.util.Date
```

Comment: *but not getting* -- what does it mean?

Comment: Doesn't `date.plusDays(1)` return a Joda `DateTime`? If so your problem is that you're trying to assign it to a Java `Date`: `val savePoint:java.util.Date=   `

Comment: `to` is method of `Seq` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq hence the error saying that to is not a member of a java.util.Date

Comment: Check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690739/creating-a-daterange-scala-joda-java

Comment: There is a similar question at codereview
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44849/construct-date-sequence-in-scala

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Using `java.time.LocalDate`, produce a stream by calling `datesUntil`, collected into a `List`.

In Java syntax (I don't know Scala):

```
LocalDate                                          // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day, and without offset-from-UTC or time zone.
.of( 2019 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 22 )                 // Specify you date in the past.
.dateUntil(                                        // Generate a Stream of LocalDate objects. 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )   // Capture the current date as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
)                                                  // Returns a `Stream< LocalDate >`. 
.collect (                                         // Collects the items provided by the stream.
    Collectors.toUnmodifiableList ()               // Instantiates an unmodifiable `List` of some indeterminate concrete class. 
)                                                  // Returns a `List` holding `LocalDate` objects.
.toString()                                        // Generates a textual listing of the collected dates using standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> [2019-09-22, 2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-25, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28, 2019-09-29, 2019-09-30, 2019-10-01, 2019-10-02, 2019-10-03]

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes, specifically `LocalDate`.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, make your intention clear by calling `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `LocalDate::datesUntil` ➙ Stream of `LocalDate` objects

You can accomplish your goal in a one-liner, by calling `LocalDate::datesUntil` to generate a stream that can be collected into a list.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "America/Edmonton" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( z );
LocalDate then = LocalDate.of ( 2019 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 22 );
List < LocalDate > dates = then.datesUntil ( today ).collect ( Collectors.toUnmodifiableList () );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "From: " + then + " to: " + today + " is: " + dates );
```

From: 2019-09-22 to: 2019-10-04 is: [2019-09-22, 2019-09-23, 2019-09-24, 2019-09-25, 2019-09-26, 2019-09-27, 2019-09-28, 2019-09-29, 2019-09-30, 2019-10-01, 2019-10-02, 2019-10-03]

### `org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`

FYI, to represent a span-of-time between a pair of dates, you can use the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class from the *ThreeTen-Extra* project.

```
LocalDateRange range = LocalDateRange.of( then , today ) ;
```

[image: Table of span-of-time classes in Java and in the ThreeTen-Extra project]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android.]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

For Scala, you can use Lamma Date (http://www.lamma.io)

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_71).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import io.lamma._
import io.lamma._

scala> Date(2015, 7, 1) to Date.today() foreach println
Date(2015,7,1)
Date(2015,7,2)
Date(2015,7,3)
Date(2015,7,4)
Date(2015,7,5)
Date(2015,7,6)
Date(2015,7,7)
```