# How to create a sequence of timestamps in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

As the question says, my goal is to create in Scala (on a Spark application) a sequence of timestamps defined at a **hourly** interval from a certain timestamp to another, and then transform this sequence to a `DataFrame`.
For instance, with the following two timestamps

```
val start_ts = "2019-11-20 00:00:00"
val end_ts = "2019-11-25 23:00:00"
```

I would like to obtain an output `DataFrame` of one column (`Date`) with all the hours from `start_ts` to `end_ts`, i.e.

```text
Date
2019-11-20 00:00:00
2019-11-20 01:00:00
2019-11-20 02:00:00
...
2019-11-25 21:00:00
2019-11-25 22:00:00
2019-11-25 23:00:00
```

Comment: So... what did you try ? it does not look like a difficult problem. What was the exact issue troubling you ? Is it about distributing it to all the worker nodes or something else ?

Comment: My issue is that I'm new to Scala and that in the docs I didn't find a function that creates hourly intervals between two timestamps

Comment: My old answer using JodaTime may be helpful. Change the `from` and `to` `DateTime` instances and the `Period` to one hour. Then convert the `Iterator` to a `DataFrame` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690739/creating-a-daterange-scala-joda-java/17691356#17691356

Comment: if you are using spark 2.4+, check built-in functions: explode + sequence: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#sequence) function for arrays by setting up the step parameter with `interval 1 hour` :

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT sequence(to_timestamp('2019-11-20 00:00:00'), to_timestamp('2019-11-25 23:00:00'), interval 1 hour) as Date")

df.printSchema()

//root
// |-- Date: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: timestamp (containsNull = false)
```

Now, just explode the array of timestamps to get the desired output:

```
df.withColumn("Date", explode($"Date")).show(5)

+-------------------+
|               Date|
+-------------------+
|2019-11-20 00:00:00|
|2019-11-20 01:00:00|
|2019-11-20 02:00:00|
|2019-11-20 03:00:00|
|2019-11-20 04:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: input two String => Output Iterator of localDateTime

```
def dayIterator(start_ts: String, end_ts: String) = {
            val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS")
            val date_start = format.parse(start_ts)
            val date_end = format.parse(end_ts)
            val start = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date_start.getTime), ZoneId.systemDefault)
            val last = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date_end.getTime), ZoneId.systemDefault)

            Iterator.iterate(start)(_ plusHours 1) takeWhile (_ isEqual last)
        }
```

And from this Iterator you can create the DataFrame

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.